# How to return array in php to $.ajax success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to return a json array back to the calling `$.ajax function`, but I only get the last item of the expected array. Maybe I don't produce an array?

If I click the button with the id "btn_getAnswers" the `"$("#btn_getAnswers").click"` gets fired and the code of `"DBCOMANSWERS"` will be executed. I want `"$result"` in "DBCOMANSWERS" to be an array filled with the values of my MYSQL-Database. I return `"$result"` formatted as JSON. The returned result should append to the paragraph with the id "output". So far, that works fine, but I except three strings to be returned and appended to the paragraph, now just a single one, the last catched entry from the database, gets appended.

I dont really can see where i have to put a loop for appending or whatever. Is the returned $result maybe not an array just the last entry of database because it gets overwritten?

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.12.3.js"></script> <!-- Import the jquery extension -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btn_getQuestion").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "DBCOMQUESTIONS.php?q=" + $("#input").val(),
                        success: function (result) { //Performs an async AJAX request
                            if (result) {
                                $("#output").html(result); //assign the value of the result to the paragraph with the id "output"
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

                $("#btn_getAnswers").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "DBCOMANSWERS.php?q=" + $("#input").val(),
                        success: function (result) { //Performs an async AJAX request
                            if (result) {
                                $("#output").append(result);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="output">This is a paragraph.</p>

        <input id="input"/>
        <button id="btn_getQuestion">Question</button>
        <button id="btn_getAnswers">Answers</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

DBCOMANSWERS.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        include("connection.php");  //includes mysqli_connent with database
        include("ErrorHandler.php"); //includes error handling function
        set_error_handler("ErrorHandler"); //set the new error handler

        $q = intval($_GET['q']);

        $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_answers WHERE QID ='".$q."'"; //define sql statement

        $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql); // get the data from the db

        while ($row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { // fetches a result row as an associative array
            $result = $row['answer'];
        }

        echo json_encode($result); // return value of $result
        mysqli_close($con); // close connection with database
    ?>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: If you return JSON in php don't include html outside only JSON.

Comment: Is there another way to return the values? `$row['answers']` just returns strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do 2 thing

remove html and add array collection. This is how your DBCOMANSWERS.php must be look like

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");  //includes mysqli_connent with database
    include("ErrorHandler.php"); //includes error handling function
    set_error_handler("ErrorHandler"); //set the new error handler

    $q = intval($_GET['q']);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_answers WHERE QID ='".$q."'"; //define sql statement

    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql); // get the data from the db
    $result = [];
    while ($row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { // fetches a result row as an associative array
        $result [] = $row['answer'];
    }
    mysqli_close($con); // close connection with database
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result); // return value of $result

?>
```

Then in your html as @madalinivascu suggests

```
success: function(result){ //Performs an async AJAX request
           result.forEach(function(i,v){
               $("#output").append(v.answer);
             })

        }}
```

Comment: Should be `$result[]` I'm guessing.

Comment: What does "remove html and add array collection." mean? How does it look like?

Comment: @flohdieter the contents of your DBCOMANSWERS.php should like like the code in this answer. See how the `<html>..` part is removed and `$result=[]` meaning it's an array.

Comment: As mentioned by @madalinivascu put header('Content-Type: application/json'); before sending result back to clientside.

Comment: @ Sameer Jain How does the final return statement look like?

Comment: my php code looks like the one above and i added `header('Content-Type: application/json');` bevor the `echo json_encode($result);` But now it will not execute my `alert(result)` in `if (result) {}`...

Comment: how does your response look like?

Comment: I tried to alert the result in my index.html but it never executes. There is no  error shown in console and I also never reach a `debugger;` in that `if(result){}`. It also dont reach a debugger above the if statement.(right after the $.ajax) short: It doesn't reach the callback function.

Comment: Look at network call in console and see how the result is fetched or if it sends any error.

Comment: I cant find anything wrong in network.The Response is empty.If i remove the header('Content-Type: application/json');it reaches the debugger; which is placed bevore the if(result){}.

Comment: I tested var_dump($result); and i got the following response: array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Christian"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Bj�rn"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Steven"
}/// but when I set the header and echo_encode the result, the response is empty

Comment: can you try $result [] = $row; instead of $result [] = $row['answer'];

Comment: now the response is : <b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use [] for reading in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\DBTEST\DBCOMANSWERS.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br /> Line 12 is: `$result[] = $row[];`

Comment: oh right, sorry, the issue is I guess json isnt getting key=>value pairs for encoding. So may be you need to setup keys in array for example $result[]['answer']=$row['answer']; Something like that

Comment: I changed the while part to : `while ($row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
        $result[] = $row[0];
    }` and now I am able to say which column I want (with the number in the brackets of $row) but I want the column [1], and that one is the only one who doesn't response something, all the other [0][2][3] response the correct values. Is it necessary that [1] datatype is varchar and all the other tinyint?

Answer (score 3):

try:
remove all html tags
and

```
include("ErrorHandler.php"); //includes error handling function
 set_error_handler("ErrorHandler"); //set the new error handler
```

from the ajaxed php file, create a array of results and append each result to it

```
    $result = []
     while ($row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { // fetches a result row as an associative array
                $result[] = $row['answer'];
            }
header('Content-Type: application/json');//change header to json format
```

In your ajax function you need to do a loop:

```
success: function(result){ //Performs an async AJAX request
               result.forEach(function(i,v){
                   $("#output").append(v.answer);
                 })

            }}
```

Comment: Still nothing, is the "return"-statement:  `echo json_encode($result);`  ok?

Comment: The HTML tags still need to be removed.

Comment: @apokryfos Do you mean the HTML tags which gets returned to the ajax call?

Comment: @flohdieter in file DBCOMANSWERS.php only keep the stuff between the `<?php ... ?>` and delete the rest.

Comment: @apokryfos done it, now the given result is just the array with the key/value pairs.thank you. But i don't know how to append them to the paragraph. @madalin ivascu I tried the loop but got the following error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in         array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Christian"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Bj�rn"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Steven"
}`

Comment: make sure no other text is echoed out or var_dump

Answer (score 1):

TRY:

```
$result = []
 while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) { // fetches a result row as an associative array
            $result[] = $row['answer'];
}
```

Reference:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
```